# firebase request email to switch devices

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

Using Firebase in unity, I know that I can send a verification email to register a new login, but I would like that when the user tries to login on another device, firebase sends a verification email confirming the action and exiting the old device, I don't if this is possible because I'm a layman in the subject

Language used is C# and I don't even know the terms to search on the internet

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDKs and products do not bound to specific devices. So there is no built-in way to get them to verify a user moving from one device to another.

The closest that exists within Firebase are its [Installation IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase/installations), which identify a specific installation (so a specific app on a specific device). If you'd associate an installation ID with each of your users, you could detect when they use a different installation ID than the one you have stored for them, and initiate a verification for the new device. But that'd be up to you to implement, as Firebase has nothing built in for such verification.